# Avoid Map Zoom Out Automatically android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I am Using Map in android. This is My OnLocationChanged Method, My App Works Correctly ,But I am Zooming My Map It Automatically Zoom Out After Few Seconds...I am Using MoveCamera Above In My Method. I am Using MapsActivity Default In Android Studio.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Location Not Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));


    }
```

Comment: first, try to understand what you are writed in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is not automatically zooming out. It zoom out because you wrote code for it

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
```

This is working everytime onLocationChanged and zooming. If you want to move your camera to new location but dont want zoom you can try newLatLngBounds function of CameraUpdateFactory

Comment: give any link for do that.